# Understanding equivalence of different definitions of discrete random variable.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables

I'm starting to study Probability theory and my professor has given the following definition:

*A random variable $X \colon \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ in a probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{A},P)$ is said to be discrete if
$$\sum_{x \in \mathbb{R}}p(x) = 1$$
where $p(x) = P(X^{-1}\{x\})$.*

I'm struggling to understand why the previous sum being $1$ implies $X$ taking a countable number of distinct values. I have already proven that the set $D = \{x \in \mathbb{R} \colon p(x)>0\}$ is countable. Therefore, if $\{x_i\}_{i=1}^{\infty}$ are all the different elements of $D$, we have that

$$\sum_{x \in \mathbb{R}}p(x) = \sum_{x \in D}p(x) = \sum_{i=1}^\infty p(x_i) = \sum_{i=1}^\infty P(X^{-1}\{x_i\}) = P\biggl( \, \bigcup_{i=1}^\infty X^{-1}\{x_i\}\biggr) = P\biggl(X^{-1}\biggl(\, \bigcup_{i=1}^\infty \, \{x_i\}\biggr)\biggr)$$
but this number being $1$ doesn't necessarily mean that $X^{-1}(\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty \{x_i\}) = \Omega$, right? Couldn't there exist uncountably many $\omega \in \Omega$ such that $p(X(\omega)) = 0$, with every $X(\omega)$ being different?

Comment: You shouldn't think about the abstract space $\Omega$. The only thing that really matters is $p(x)$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's possible for a discrete random variable to take uncountably many values on a set of probability $0$.  However, these values are irrelevant from the point of view of probability theory.  Two random variables are considered as equivalent if they are equal almost surely, i.e. except on a set of probability $0$.  If a random variable $X$ is discrete according to the definition you gave, then $\mathbb P(X \in D) = 1$.  Or equivalently, it is equal almost surely to a random variable that takes values in a countable set.